# How to change the value of string from a cout

Tags: string

```
void extractWord (string& str)
```

I have to write a function that extracts the word between ‘*’. 
For example, using the three test cases below:

`string s = "This is to be *reversed*"`

`string s1 ="*Reversed* starts here";`

`string s2 = "This is *in* the middle";`

and after each function call,
`s=reversed, s1=Reversed, s2=in`

So i figured out...

```
void extractWord (string& str)

{
char target= '*';

int idx1=0;

while (str[idx1] != target)
idx1=idx1+1;

int idx2=idx1+1;
while (str[idx2] != target)
idx2=idx2+1;

for(int i=0;i<sizeof(str);i++)
     {
     if ((i>idx1)&&(i<idx2))
     cout<<str[i];
     }
}


int main()
{
string s="This is to be *reversed*";
string s1 = "*Reversed* starts here";
string s2= "This is *in* the middle";

extractWord(s);
cout<<endl;
extractWord(s1);
cout<<endl;
extractWord(s2);
cout<<endl;
}
```

but how do I change the value of s into the output of this function?

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code a bit. I hope this solves your problem:

```
//#include "stdafx.h"
#include < string >
#include < iostream >
using namespace std;

void extractWord (string& str)

{
char target= '*';

int idx1=0;

while (str[idx1] != target)
idx1=idx1+1;

int idx2=idx1+1;
while (str[idx2] != target)
idx2=idx2+1;

str=str.substr(idx1+1,idx2-idx1-1); //changed 
}


int main()
{
string s="This is to be *reversed*";
string s1 = "*Reversed* starts here";
string s2= "This is *in* the middle";

extractWord(s);
cout<<s<<endl; //changed 
extractWord(s1);
cout<<s1<<endl; //changed 
extractWord(s2);
cout<<s2<<endl; //changed 

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Now, every time you call void extractWord (string& str) it replaces string with only word between *'s.
I've used std::string::substr function. > http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/

Other option is to make function that returns word between *'s.

```
//#include "stdafx.h"
#include < string >
#include < iostream >
using namespace std;

string extractWord (string& str)

{
char target= '*';

int idx1=0;

while (str[idx1] != target)
idx1=idx1+1;

int idx2=idx1+1;
while (str[idx2] != target)
idx2=idx2+1;

return str.substr(idx1+1,idx2-idx1-1);
}


int main()
{
string s="This is to be *reversed*";
string s1 = "*Reversed* starts here";
string s2= "This is *in* the middle";
string res;
res=extractWord(s);
cout<<res<<endl;
res=extractWord(s1);
cout<<res<<endl;
res=extractWord(s2);
cout<<res<<endl;

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

However, note that it doesn't work if your string do not contain two *'s or it has more than one word that has to be extracted. I hope this helped you.